# Why is Canvas.style Display block not working?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I'm working on a map project using javascript canvas and the canvas.style('display', 'block') is showing the map as blank.

I've tried setting up the line of code in a function setting up the canvas as well as reorganizing the function since order matters. I've tried setting up the style in the css section above the script.

```
let myMap;
let canvas;
const mappa = new Mappa('Leaflet');
const options = {
    lat: 39.810,
    lng: -98.555,
    zoom: 5,
    style: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
}
function setup(){
    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    canvas.style('display', 'block');
    myMap = mappa.tileMap(options);
    myMap.overlay(canvas);
}
```

I'm trying to fill the window with the map without the default scrollbars on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`createCanvas` is not a native javascript method. To create an canvas element use:

```
function setup(){
    canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    canvas.style('display', 'block');
    // ...
}
```

To call `createCanvas` you need to import [p5js](https://p5js.org/) library.

Comment: I have the p5js library in my head section already. I can already get my map to open and everything, I just can't get it to fit to my window without the scroll bars. Is it possible to do this with the createCanvas method with the library imported?

Comment: You updated your question right? Your javascript error is fixed, now you got a css problem?